# Create a Service for the User Provider

Tags: silex

I created a custom user class with a custom userProvider based on [following link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#index-0)

I'm unable to create a Service for the User Provider.

```
$app->setParameter(
    'webservice_user_provider.class',
    'Tac\WebserviceUserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider'
);
$app->setDefinition(
    'webservice_user_provider',
    new Definition('%webservice_user_provider.class%')
);
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Silex\Application::setParameter() in http://content.api.com/Users/davyd/Sites/content_api/src/boot.php on line 119

Answer (score 2):

Silex is not the Symfony2 framework, so Symfony2's documentation does not apply.

Have a look at http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html for documentation on how to define services in Silex.

```
$app['some_service'] = $app->share(function () {
    return new Service();
});
```

Comment: Symfony2's documentation does not *always* apply. The component docs in fact *do* apply. It's just the framework parts that do not.